# mapping train data to meta data

Tags: r, mapping, geo

I want to convert meta data mapping train data. Because longitude and latitude is not worth for my train data. So i will use mean of distance of meta data. I've tried merge function but it's no good.

**Example :**

**1) train data**

```
station  log  lat
      A  123  127
      B  121  126
      C  127  129
      D  113  118
      E  119  118
```

**2) meta data**

```
from  to
   A   C
   B   C
   A   D
   A   E
   D   E
```

**3) Desired Output**

```
from fromlog fromlat tolog tolat
   A     123     127   127   129
   B     121     126   127   129
   A     123     127   113   118
   A     123     127   119   118
   D     113     118   119   118
```

Comment: Can you explain your desired output ? Not clear to me.

Comment: It doesn't have to be desired output. In the train data, it have log and lat info. But the meta data just have name or code(Exactly, it also have different information, for example time or user age.). So, i want to convert 'from' and 'to' column to ' fromlog', 'fromlat' 'tolog', and 'tolat' using 'log' and 'lat' in the train data. Then i will use metadata for train data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can use `match`, inside a `lapply` call

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, unlist(lapply(df2, function(x) {
     inds <- match(x, df1$station)
     list(log = df1$log[inds], lat = df1$lat[inds])
}), recursive = FALSE))

#  from.log from.lat to.log to.lat
#1      123      127    127    129
#2      121      126    127    129
#3      123      127    113    118
#4      123      127    119    118
#5      113      118    119    118
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(station = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), log = c(123L, 
121L, 127L, 113L, 119L), lat = c(127L, 126L, 129L, 118L, 118L
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(from = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "D"), to = c("C", 
"C", "D", "E", "E")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- inner_join(df1, df2,  by = c('station' =  'to')) %>%
    select(tolog = log, tolat = lat) 
d2 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c('station' = 'from')) %>%
    select(fromlog = log, fromlat = lat)
bind_cols(df2 %>% 
             select(from), d2, d1)
```

Comment: It's not a good answer.. Because it can make more observation than df2.